# How to open from my app "Tell A Friend" function in itunes

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

I want to known, if is possible by code, open itunes function "tell a friend", for sending via mail link & photo of my app in itunes.

If not possibile I think the only way is by using **MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate** and creating a self-made mail ... but it is hard for including images into mail...

thank you

Comment: u want to share your app link?

Comment: I want to 'reuse' the function 'tell a friend' in itunes for sharing my app information (in itunes like: link, size, author, downloads..) instead create my own function (into my code) and make by myself the mail.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can only do this by mail only, and images are also not hard, just use this message of MFMailComposer to atach images with the mail

```
- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData *)attachment mimeType:(NSString *)mimeType fileName:(NSString *)filename
```

Comment: I founded a really best implementation instead of adding attachment to the mail.

`NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(emailImage)];
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];
    
[emailBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'></b></p>",base64String]];`

Answer (score 1):

You could use MFMailComposeViewController and just make an html based message where you don't attach your image but rather host it on a server or use the image hosted by iTunes.

Comment: yes, this is my current idea. but I prefer had a simple way for get the info of my app, like author, rank, category etc... and itunes give me this informations in the proper language. 0 work for me and a really nice implementation...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_HERE]];
```

Specify the iTunes url where URL_HERE appears and when that code is executed Safari will open pointing to the iTunes page.

Comment: ehm, the problem is... how I cant take URL_HERE from itunes. It is a button, I can't read the link ..

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the somthing similar and I found the "iTellAfriend" class. It works for me.

Download this source code from [github/iTellafriend](https://github.com/aporat/iTellAFriend).